# alert-ing return value of ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, event-loop

(1.  Do you find it useful to have a global jQuery ajax 'helper' that you can call `ajax(url,data,async)` ? )

```
function ajax(ajax_url, ajax_data, ajax_async){
  ajax_async = typeof(ajax_async) != 'undefined' ? ajax_async : true;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: ajax_url,
    data: ajax_data,
    async: ajax_async,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(response) {
        return response;
    },
    error: function(){

    }
  });
}
```

If I'm calling a function that places a GET and returns the success response.

```
alert(ajax('localhost/hello','',false);
```

If I do `alert(get_ajax())` I get an alert of 'undefined'.. even if there was a return value

I see its an event loop issue, but I `async:false` in the ajax call. thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those questions that has been asked a million times, but it's nearly impossible to search. Anyway, the problem is that when you return from here...

```
success: function(response) {
    return response;
}
```

...you're not returning from the `ajax()` function but the anonymous `success` function. To return the value from the main function you have to save the string to a variable so that you can return from the correct function.

```
var val = '';

$.ajax({
    //       ....
    success: function(response) {
       val = response;
    },
    //       ....
});

return val;
```

Note that this only works when you're making a synchronous call. For asynchronous calls it's better to give a callback function as an argument and use it as the success function.

Answer (score 1):

For an synchronous call, I believe you would do

```
var data;
$.ajax({
    ...
    async: false,
    success: function(response) {
        data = response;
    }
});
return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ajax` function wraps the `$.ajax` call, does doesn't return anything: that's where the `undefined` comes from. To get some value in your `alert` example, you should add a return statement at the bottom of your function.

To get an alert with the response, the following should do:

```
success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
},
```

Comment: But i need to return the response. I get a value if i alert() inside the success, but not when i alert() the ajax fnction.

Comment: Well, if it is asynchronous, you can't get the response directly since the ajax call isn't blocking: it will only be available once the `success` callback function is called. Whatever you want to do with that data, you'll have to refactor your code to allow it to be updated from the `success` callback. Can't you move all your code that is affected by this call to be used _after_ the ajax call has been completed?

Comment: was my mistake, i left out that i set it to synchronous